# Trying to understand SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable output format

Tags: ssl, environment-variables, wireshark

I have been messing around with the SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable, and I am trying to understand what everything inside the output that it gives me (the .log file with all the session keys). 
Here is a picture of what the output looks like:
[image]

I understand that these are keys, but what I notice is a space in the middle of each line, indicating to me that they are separate keys. What exactly are the 2 different keys that they are giving me, and how is WireShark able to use this file to decrypt ssl traffic?

Comment: see this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites/42350#42350) if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in a comment from [the commmit that added this feature](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blobdiff;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ssl-utils.c;h=d2b4b40741c25dbe8a1adb41e4ba5ac24c1ff147;hp=62325b663f946885f0dfea80eaf2e29f51f9bba0;hb=75319f09a9da005de341812da02e3e28db765470;hpb=cec562ddd2949fc3e19000eccc79e6962e4bae5c):

```
     *   - "CLIENT_RANDOM xxxx yyyy"
     *     Where xxxx is the client_random from the ClientHello (hex-encoded)
     *     Where yyy is the cleartext master secret (hex-encoded)
     *     (This format allows non-RSA SSL connections to be decrypted, i.e.
     *     ECDHE-RSA.)
```